# Javascript - Get unique and sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have an array with duplicate items. I want to filter that array to return only unique items, but that items have to be **sorted based on how many times** they were in initial array.

```
const initialArr = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 1
  }, 
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
];

const expectedSortedResult = [
  {
    id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you already try to solve it by yourself, and if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @pduersteler on the beginning

Comment: Research Reduce https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce to do your "groupBy", then research Sort https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort to sort by your "groupBy" count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to always post your attempt, no matter how far away from the solution it is.

You should research the following (and I solved it with these too):

Reduce (create object, groupBy and create __count property): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Convert this back to an array with `Object.values()`, Followed by

Sort (sort by __count): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Then you will need to delete that count property if you don't want it in your output, you can do this with Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
const initialArr = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 1}, 
  {id: 2},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 3},
];

const output = Object.values(initialArr.reduce((aggObj, item) => {      
  if (aggObj[item.id]){
    aggObj[item.id].__count += 1
  }
  else{
    aggObj[item.id] = item;
    aggObj[item.id].__count = 1
  }      
  return aggObj;
}, {}))
      .sort((a,b) => b.__count - a.__count)
      .map(a => {delete a.__count; return a});
      
      
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```